How to add spacing below a CSS grid and start a new grid
I have one grid that displays a bunch of buttons to the left of the screen. On the right of the screen is a grid (though I don't know if it really needs to be) that shows contact information.
I am trying to insert a third grid below both of the first two that will have a separate series of buttons. But, when I try to insert that third grid, it shows up in between the first and second grids.
The only way I can get the third grid to be below the first two is if I put in a banner div before the third grid, but then the banner is floated to the right.


div {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.banner {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  font-size: 46px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px;
}

.buttonGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-end: auto;
  grid-row-end: auto;
  float: left;
  gap: 5px;
  width: 75px;
  height: auto;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
  align-content: center;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
}

.pocTable {
  /* this is the one I don't know if it needs to be a grid, but I can't get it to display how I want without it being a grid */
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  display: grid;
}

.usefulLinks {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
}

.usefulLinks div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.usefulLinks>div:first-child {
  grid-column: span 3;
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
<div class="banner">banner</div>

<div class="buttonGrid">
  <div class="buttons">things and stuff</div>
  <div class="buttons">things and stuff</div>
  <div class="buttons">things and stuff</div>
  <div class="buttons">things and stuff</div>
  <div class="buttons">things and stuff</div>
  <div class="buttons">things and stuff</div>
  <div class="buttons">things and stuff</div>
  <div class="buttons">things and stuff</div>
  <div class="buttons">things and stuff</div>
  <div class="buttons">things and stuff</div>
</div>

<div class="pocTable">
  <div class="pocHeader">contact info:</div>
  <div class="pocText"><b>Phone: </b> 123-4567</div>
  <div class="pocText"><b>Email: </b> email@email.com</div>
  <div class="pocHeader">manager:</div>
  <div class="pocText">First Last</div>
  <div class="pocHeader">manager:</div>
  <div class="pocText">First Last</div>
</div>

<div></div>

<div class="usefulLinks">
  <div>useful links</div>
  <div>first</div>
  <div>second</div>
  <div>third</div>
</div>



As stated before, if I put <div class="banner">useful links</div> in between the <div class="pocTable"> and <div class="usefulLinks"> grids, it will shift the usefulLinks grid down, but then the banner is floating off the the right.

Have you tried to wrap your first two elements in a single div or section element and style it so it is block, then add a second element with your next grid elements below that?

Perhaps you could also add a visual layout that shows what you are after.

"...[It] shows up in between the first and second grids." - this is why we (mostly) don't use float for layouts any more. You're already aware of - and using - CSS grid, please: stick with the more modern layout approaches: CSS grid (MDN, CSS Tricks)and CSS flex (MDN, CSS Tricks) (at the time of writing).

@dalelandry this is ideally what I would like it to look like: https://imgur.com/UzzegZD
Ideally, each of those "icons" would be clickable and link to an external site. Doing all that is a future endeavor in this journey of mine but, for now, I'm just stuck at having the separation between the top portion of where the "things and stuff" buttons and contact info sections are and then the useful links section below it

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but I edited your code a bit and made it so that the useful links are below the other two. Here is the link to see what I did - https://codepen.io/Matthew-Wright-the-sans/pen/yLmeoMO
Tell me if this helps
    *{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
div {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.banner {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  font-size: 46px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px;
}

.buttonGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4 , 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-end: auto;
  grid-row-end: auto;
  gap: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  justify-content:center;
  float:left;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
  align-content: center;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
}

.pocTable { /* this is the one I don't know if it needs to be a grid, but I can't get it to display how I want without it being a grid */
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  width:50%;
  float:right;
}

.usefulLinks {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  width:100%;
}

.usefulLinks div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.usefulLinks > div:first-child {
  grid-column: span 3;
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


Thank you, Matthew! This does help. Would you be able to explain how what you changed in the code allowed for the usefulLinks grid to be below the other portions?
